# LDAP authentication in asp.net MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net, authentication, ldap, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 applicationand I want to add LDAP authentication.
I already have a form page which is a startup page which tell the user to enter his name and password. The form page is redirected after submit to a home page without testing anything.
I don't know now how to verify if the user exists or not using ldap authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this MS ActiveDirectory LDAP? If so you will want to take a look at ASP.Net Identity: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity